# Why is floating debris above a vortex stationary with respect to the container?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, home-experiment

I noticed the phenomenon that a spinning vortex with an initially corotating surface (as identifiable from the movement of floating debris or bubbles in it) appears to quickly stop spinning when viewed from above (the debris on the surface are not moving) but when viewed from below, one can see debris whirling around.

It seems reasonable that forces between the air and the water at the interface should cause the water speed there to be *slower* than deeper in the fluid. The surface and floating objects have drag with the air, which blows away, dissipating the kinetic energy. If drag was the only relevant force, the surface layer should slow until it was somewhat slower than the layer underneath and somewhat faster than the air, resulting in 0 net force at some nonzero velocity.

However, floating objects on the surface are not just *slower*, they  rapidly become *stationary* with respect to the container. (I confirmed this experimentally with my cup of soapy water - the surface rapidly becomes stationary *with respect to the container*, not the room, whether the container is sitting still, translating, or rotating. Although admittedly, dancing around the kitchen with a cup of soapy water may not be the most rigorously repeatable experimental procedure.)

*A previous, now discarded hypthesis -  see the edit below.*

> I have a guess that surface tension might be involved, with the
> adhesive force at the water-glass interface on the sides acting as an
> "anchor" and the surface tension acting as a "fabric" that propagates
> the adhesive force across the water-air interface, but not through the
> lower layers of fluid. However, I don't actually understand the
> mechanics behind my proposed mechanism, so really I'm just sticking
> science words to the problem like a clueless Star Trek character.

What forces cause this phenomenon and how?

[image]

Link: a very short video of this phenomenon with debris from a poached egg.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYj8z.jpg

EDIT:
Further experimentation rules out my surface tension hypothesis, so I'm deleting that tag. It also changes my assessment of the phenomenon, so I'm changing the title question and a little of the phrasing above.

I tried the experiment again, this time using black pepper sprinkled onto the spinning liquid. Black pepper is close to neutrally buoyant (at least when wet), and surface tension keeps most of it on the surface. It spun just like the liquid underneath, with a similar angular velocity. This indicates that my earlier assessment that the surface layer stops spinning quickly is false. Also it indicates that my surface tension hypothesis is false.

I repeated the experiment with the soap bubbles again and got the same results as before.

Further thoughts:

Lighter-than-water objects float to the center under centrifugal force. Could this have something to do with them coming to a stop?

Maybe I'm mistaken about the container being the relevant reference. Perhaps the walls of the container, which extend higher than the surface of the liquid, create air currents which match the motion of the container, such that when I measure an object that is stationary with respect to the air, it appears to be stationary with respect to the container accidentally.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the setup, you are rotating a container (say a cup) holding some fluid inside (say soapy water) and you observe that at the interface of the air, the fluid is stationary with respect to the container, but in the bulk continues to rotate? (perhaps a small illustration would make it clearer)

Comment: I stirred the fluid with a spoon initially. On removing the spoon, it is as you describe, whether or not the container is rotating.

Comment: @lpz I have added an illustration and a short video.

Comment: In your footage, there's a bubble near the top edge of the video, that lies on the surface and is being carried by the rotating fluid, indicating that the surface itself is rotating - it looks like it's just the little pile of foamy debris in the center that's stationary.

Comment: To add in @FilipMilovanović, it looks like the flow is simply one of uniform rotation (looking at the debris of the video). Since it vanishes at the center, the foam there is actually stationary with respect to the fluid and the patch is of finite size due to its “coherence”. Furthermore, you’d expect a slight parabolic indent, which could explain the relative large amount of foam accumulated at the center.

Comment: @lpz  accumulation of foam at the center and the slight parabolic indent are consequences of the same thing - the direction of down has a radially outward component in the circularly accelerated frames; lighter than water objects float to the center of the top while heavier than water objects sink to the sides of the bottom.